# Boolean expression with a redundant overlapping term

Tags: boolean, expression, kivy-language

I have simplified a Boolean expression using 14 `Boolean` Algebra law steps and now have a working resultant function which according to a KV map still has a redundant term.

In an attempt to remove this term I have tried various distribution, complement and identity applications followed by a `deMorgans law`, as well a Consensus Theorem approach. Of the text books I've consulted they all say there is no theory or set rules to resolving such an issue, just experience!

After much simplification (page and half) my resultant expression is,

```
z = ~a~cd + b~a  + b~d + bc [1]
```

Using a KV map I get a slightly simpler expression of,

```
z = ~a~cd + b~d + bc [2]
```

The truth table of each expression is equivalent therefore the b~a of my first expression [1] appears to be redundant.

I expected to be able to cancel the redundant `**b~a**` function by applying the laws of Boolean algebra but after much experimenting I'm unable to find an entry point.

This is an assignment question so I do not expect anybody to do my homework but advise on how to approach this challenge would be appreciated.

Comment: Should not the reduced expression be `~AB + BC + ~A~CD` ?

Comment: P.W it is close but not identical

Comment: That's what I got using karnaugh map.